# How can I find out the dimensions/resolution of a downloaded video file?

Tags: tablet, video

My only device = An Android tablet (4.0.3), **no laptop**.

Long ago, I used to have a laptop, but circumstances have left me with (technology wise) only an Android tablet (4.0.3). When I used to have a laptop, I used VLC not only to watch videos that I downloaded & collected, but also to check on what a specific video's dimensions were (examples = 480x360, 640x480, 1280x720, 1920x1080).

Now that I only have a tablet, I have looked for a way to do this, but with zero success. I have tried lots of video players for Android including VLC's own app & none of them have the option to show *any* information about a video file. I use such information because the videos that I download always have more than one size available (dimensionals wise), but never identify the dimensions that any file has.

So, if anybody knows a way to find out the dimensions of a specific video file that I have downloaded & have on my tablet, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) provides a way to check video resolution. All you have to do is install and open MX Player, touch hold the video file until you see some options and **select properties**. There you can find resolution listed as well as other codec information.

Besides, [VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon&hl=en) also shows the resolution. Install and open the app, left-swipe and choose **Video** option. There you can find all the videos scanned by VLC with resolution already listed on them. However, if you choose **Directories** option, then you can't see the resolution.

Comment: Thanks Firelord. This helps me (among others) more than most people would believe. I didn't notice that VLC for android can do that because I was always making the 'mistake' of directly clicking on a video file & choosing to play it with VLC, in which case you get almost zero options. They should let you see a "media/file info" screen/menu while it's playing a video file, which most other versions of VLC can do. It would NEVER have occurred to me to start VLC WITHOUT a video file because that's VLC's only reason to exist.